# Scraping a website with scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

sHey I've just started using scrapy and was trying it out on a website "diy.com" but i cant seem to get the CrawlSpider to follow links or scrape any data. I think it might be my regex but i cant see anything

any help will be appreciated

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from items import PartItem

class DIY_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'diy_cat'
    allowed_domains = ['diy.com']

    start_urls =[
        "http://www.diy.com/nav/decor/tiles/wall-tiles"

    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/(nav)/(decor)/(\w*)/(.*)(\d*)$', ),deny=(r'(.*)/(jsp)/(.*)')), callback='parse_item',follow = True),

def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        tests =[]
        test = PartItem()

        if sel.xpath('//*[@id="fullWidthContent"]/div[2]/dl/dd[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/text()') :
            price = sel.xpath('//*[@id="fullWidthContent"]/div[2]/dl/dd[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/text()')
        else:
            price= sel.xpath('//dd[@class="item_cta"]/ul[@class="fright item_price"]/li/text()').extract()
        if not price:
           return test





return test
```

Comment: It's actually following links. At least `parse_item()` is called. Post the complete code of your spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides, @Talvalin's note, you are not getting actual prices.

Try this version of `parse_item`:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    price_list = sel.xpath('//span[@class="onlyPrice"]/text()').extract()
    for price in price_list:
        if price:
            item = PartItem()
            item['price'] = price
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule states `parse_item` as the callback but the actual callback is named `parse_items`. Additionally, the indenting for the `parse_items` function is incorrect, but that could simply be a formatting issue when pasting the code in.